# Is this alternative statement for rank-nullity theorem correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The statement says: the number of variables in a homogeneous system is always equal to the dimension of the row space of the coefficient matrix plus the number of parameters in the general solution of the homogeneous system.

As I looked at the rank-nullity theorem, it does not restrict the system as heterogeneous or homogeneous as this one does. However, I generally feel that the statement is correct. could someone point out exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

It's only true for a hetereogeneous system that *has* solutions.  Otherwise, it's impossible to make sense of "number of parameters in the general solution".

If at least one solution exists, then there is a correspondence between the solutions of the heterogeneous system and the solutions of the corresponding homogeneous system, so the number of parameters is the same, and this is a true statement.

Comment: Nice answer, thanks!